# SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween() vs Location.distanceBetween()

Tags: android, google-maps

What's the difference between Google Maps Android API Utility Library [SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween()](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#computeDistanceBetween-LatLng-LatLng-) and Android [Location.distanceBetween()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double, double, double, double, float[]))?

They both calculate the distance in meters between two geographical locations.

Which one should I use in Android?

Edit: for some reason the markdown link isn't working properly, even though it's fine in the preview...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween()`](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.java#L173) calculates radian distance between locations and times it by [`EART_RADIUS`](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/MathUtil.java#L29)

[`Location.distanceBetween()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/location/Location.java#391) is based on http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PUBS_LIB/inverse.pdf and using the "Inverse Formula". Distance is defined using the WGS84 ellipsoid.

IMO it better to use `Location.distanceBetween()`, it tend to be more precise.

Comment: Which one takes more resources (CPU)?

Answer (score 0):

distanceTo() gives accurate result as compared to SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween()