# Location.distanceBetween shows 0

Tags: android, kotlin, android-location

I want to do an application that counts the runner's distance, but distanceBetween provided by LocationManager still shows 0. I have speed and it works fine, so onLocationChanged function is fine, but I'm doing something wrong in getting the distance.

```
override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location?) {
    val speed : Double = (location!!.speed * 3600 / 1000).toDouble()
    updateUI(speed)

    lat_text_view.text = location.latitude.toString()
    lon_text_view.text = location.longitude.toString()

    val startLat: Double = location.latitude
    val startLon: Double = location.longitude
    val endLat: Double = location.latitude
    val endLon: Double = location.longitude

    val results = FloatArray(1)
    Location.distanceBetween(startLat, startLon, endLat, endLon, results)

    distance_text_view.text = results[0].toString()
}
```

Comment: your `endLat` is same as `startLat` and `endLon` is same as `endLon`

Comment: Where to get other values?

Comment: You know it better. Distance depends on 2 `LatLng` values. First decide which 2 `LatLng` distance you need.

Comment: _"Where to get other values?"_ You'll store the start position's coordinates in variables whose scope is outside the `onLocationChanged()` method. So, they could be members of the class inside which `onLocationChanged()` is.

Comment: You are right! Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am a java programmer.. So I gave you a java solution please convert it in kotlin..

```
 //here arguments should be latlng objects.   
 double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(firstLatLong, SecondLatLng);
```

In java latlong objects can be formed as follow..you can convert it too kotlin.

```
LatLng firstLatLong = new LatLng(firstlocationObject.getLat(), firstlocationObject.getLon());
```

Comment: I am not sure, but SphericalUtil is not very accurate. I'll wait for an answer to distanceBetween. If no one solves my problem, I'll use your code

Comment: your method for distance gives the route distance between two points.. and my one gives the Spherical distance(independent on route) most probably the shortest distance.. That's the difference. hopefully you get it

Comment: _"your method for distance gives the route distance between two points"_ No it doesn't. (If I correctly understood what you mean by "route distance".) The `Location` class knows nothing about streets, roads and routing.

Comment: thanks bro.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018852/sphericalutil-computedistancebetween-vs-location-distancebetween , this link clears everything.